# Angular Interpolation with a JSON-Object containing / in a key

Tags: html, json, angular

I try to get the value of a JSON object from my TypeScript component. It's working for all keys except one that contains a / in the key (e.g. "a/b": 10)

PS: .["a/b"] is also not working.

Comment: did you try {{yourJsonVariable | json}} ? Use the json pipe

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) for the same.

Try this without any `.`

```
obj["a/b"]
```